# Telegram.py : Buttons creating

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently making a Telegram using Python. I was wondering how to make a functional buttons like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3eMb.png

I would like to make `/command` command to have button that says "This is a button". How do I make it? Here's my code to help :

```
# Modules needed
import time
from time import sleep
import random
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# /command
def command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Reply here")

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("[TOKEN]", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("command", command))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are so called inline buttons. Check out the [official docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) and this `python-telegram-bot` [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I tested and modified it. I now have another problem. Bot only Say You choose : [option] from all the three buttons. I want to make the bot have different response on every button

Comment: You can do that by handling the `CallbackQueries` differently depending on the `callback_data`. Either check the `callback_data` directly in the button callback or use the `pattern` argument of `CallbackQueryHandler`. See also https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#inlinekeyboard2py for a more elaborate example including `ConversationHandler`

Comment: Can you visualize it using code? Perharps I understand easier than explanation.

Comment: That's what I linked the example for ;)

Comment: But I still don't understand how to handle CallbackQueries differently 