# Where does the inLineKeyboardButton respond when the user clicks on it

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
enter def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
"""Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
    ],
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')],
]

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup) here
```

I know that 'Option 1' is the name that the button displays and callback_data is the data that is called back in, but · I don't know where this InlineKeyboardButton will respond to the pressed event,Or in which function will this callback_data be passed to be executed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telegram.py : Buttons creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761213/telegram-py-buttons-creating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use handler to get callback data

```
updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(c_back_respons))
```

then you can use function like this

```
def c_back_respons(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    call_back_data = update.callback_query.data
    if call_back_data in ("1"):
        function(update)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answers are very useful to me